# Hibernate Search: concurrent timeout exception

Tags: java, hibernate, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

**Scenario:**
I am processing an excel file containing 150+columns and 15000 rows. This file converted to List and then called repository.saveAll(List) . This service method was called concurently by 15 user request.

**Code**

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public BooleanResponse fileProcessing(
            Request req) {


        for (MultipartFile file : req.getMasterSheets()) {
            List<EntityClazz> list = excelParser.processExcelFile(file, EntityClazz.class);
            EntityClazzRepository.saveAll(list);
            list.clear();
        }

        return BooleanResponse.success();

    }
```

I am facing following exception with Hibernate Search and Elastic Search.

```
2019-11-14 12:38:32.567 ERROR 1 --- [eout executor-1] o.h.s.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler     : HSEARCH000058: Exception occurred org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH400007: Elasticsearch request failed.
Request: POST /_bulk with parameters {refresh=false}
Response: null
Subsequent failures:
        Entity com.xyz.xyz.domain.entity.epc.EntityClazz  Id 436294  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.AddLuceneWork
        Entity com.xyz.xyz.domain.entity.epc.EntityClazz  Id 436310  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.AddLuceneWork
        Entity com.xyz.xyz.domain.entity.epc.EntityClazz  Id 436326  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.AddLuceneWork
        Entity com.xyz.xyz.domain.entity.epc.EntityClazz  Id 436342  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.AddLuceneWork
.
.
.
.

        Entity com.xyz.xyz.domain.entity.epc.EntityClazz  Id 472620  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.AddLuceneWork
        Entity com.xyz.xyz.domain.entity.epc.EntityClazz  Id 472625  Work Type  org.hibernate.search.backend.AddLuceneWork




org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH400007: Elasticsearch request failed.
Request: POST /_bulk with parameters {refresh=false}
Response: null
        at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.work.impl.BulkWork.lambda$execute$1(BulkWork.java:77) ~[hibernate-search-elasticsearch-5.10.5.Final.jar!/:5.10.5.Final]
        at org.hibernate.search.util.impl.Futures.lambda$handler$1(Futures.java:57) ~[hibernate-search-engine-5.10.5.Final.jar!/:5.10.5.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:870) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:852) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.DefaultElasticsearchClient.lambda$send$3(DefaultElasticsearchClient.java:137) ~[hibernate-search-elasticsearch-5.10.5.Final.jar!/:5.10.5.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
        ... 8 common frames omitted
```

This log is one such example of many exceptions printed out... Feels like there are many threads working and some how failed. Don't know why.. Data set which needs to be indexed was almost 50000 at one time. and Hibernate search starts indexing automatically and asynchronously after transaction commit as I have set async true.

I am using Hibernate Search version 5.10 and elastic search version 5.6.10.
My database table is very large. and There is bulk update/insert operation is performed by Hibernate on this table.

My Elastic Search Server is on default configuration. that only one node. yellow health.

Here is Elastic Search Cluster Node stats:

```
{
   "_nodes":{
      "total":1,
      "successful":1,
      "failed":0
   },
   "cluster_name":"elasticsearch",
   "nodes":{
      "I7fWwFhORhimHRDL6jJTuw":{
         "timestamp":1573740483870,
         "name":"I7fWwFh",
         "transport_address":"",
         "host":"",
         "ip":"",
         "roles":[
            "master",
            "data",
            "ingest"
         ],
         "indices":{
            "docs":{
               "count":7090,
               "deleted":956
            },
            "store":{
               "size_in_bytes":69228643,
               "throttle_time_in_millis":0
            },
            "indexing":{
               "index_total":5091795,
               "index_time_in_millis":60401979,
               "index_current":11,
               "index_failed":7,
               "delete_total":124964,
               "delete_time_in_millis":2232,
               "delete_current":0,
               "noop_update_total":0,
               "is_throttled":true,
               "throttle_time_in_millis":1348474
            },
            "get":{
               "total":4913,
               "time_in_millis":316,
               "exists_total":4913,
               "exists_time_in_millis":316,
               "missing_total":0,
               "missing_time_in_millis":0,
               "current":0
            },
            "search":{
               "open_contexts":0,
               "query_total":232976,
               "query_time_in_millis":79853,
               "query_current":0,
               "fetch_total":183622,
               "fetch_time_in_millis":608420,
               "fetch_current":0,
               "scroll_total":3555,
               "scroll_time_in_millis":192717,
               "scroll_current":0,
               "suggest_total":0,
               "suggest_time_in_millis":0,
               "suggest_current":0
            },
            "merges":{
               "current":0,
               "current_docs":0,
               "current_size_in_bytes":0,
               "total":9867,
               "total_time_in_millis":23061388,
               "total_docs":7412149,
               "total_size_in_bytes":191974966202,
               "total_stopped_time_in_millis":0,
               "total_throttled_time_in_millis":626635,
               "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes":80244256738
            },
            "refresh":{
               "total":200577,
               "total_time_in_millis":32611981,
               "listeners":0
            },
            "flush":{
               "total":7747,
               "total_time_in_millis":67635
            },
            "warmer":{
               "current":0,
               "total":677,
               "total_time_in_millis":21
            },
            "query_cache":{
               "memory_size_in_bytes":0,
               "total_count":0,
               "hit_count":0,
               "miss_count":0,
               "cache_size":0,
               "cache_count":0,
               "evictions":0
            },
            "fielddata":{
               "memory_size_in_bytes":0,
               "evictions":0
            },
            "completion":{
               "size_in_bytes":0
            },
            "segments":{
               "count":48,
               "memory_in_bytes":4551470,
               "terms_memory_in_bytes":3595446,
               "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes":20168,
               "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes":0,
               "norms_memory_in_bytes":913856,
               "points_memory_in_bytes":280,
               "doc_values_memory_in_bytes":21720,
               "index_writer_memory_in_bytes":0,
               "version_map_memory_in_bytes":0,
               "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes":0,
               "max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp":-1,
               "file_sizes":{

               }
            },
            "translog":{
               "operations":0,
               "size_in_bytes":1290
            },
            "request_cache":{
               "memory_size_in_bytes":21920,
               "evictions":0,
               "hit_count":0,
               "miss_count":30
            },
            "recovery":{
               "current_as_source":0,
               "current_as_target":0,
               "throttle_time_in_millis":0
            }
         },
         "os":{
            "timestamp":1573740483888,
            "cpu":{
               "percent":0,
               "load_average":{
                  "1m":0,
                  "5m":0,
                  "15m":0
               }
            },
            "mem":{
               "total_in_bytes":4134809600,
               "free_in_bytes":115888128,
               "used_in_bytes":4018921472,
               "free_percent":3,
               "used_percent":97
            },
            "swap":{
               "total_in_bytes":0,
               "free_in_bytes":0,
               "used_in_bytes":0
            },
            "cgroup":{
               "cpuacct":{
                  "control_group":"/",
                  "usage_nanos":85077837036370
               },
               "cpu":{
                  "control_group":"/",
                  "cfs_period_micros":100000,
                  "cfs_quota_micros":-1,
                  "stat":{
                     "number_of_elapsed_periods":0,
                     "number_of_times_throttled":0,
                     "time_throttled_nanos":0
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "process":{
            "timestamp":1573740483888,
            "open_file_descriptors":213,
            "max_file_descriptors":65536,
            "cpu":{
               "percent":0,
               "total_in_millis":82774150
            },
            "mem":{
               "total_virtual_in_bytes":5024968704
            }
         },
         "jvm":{
            "timestamp":1573740483888,
            "uptime_in_millis":2672036639,
            "mem":{
               "heap_used_in_bytes":1155032416,
               "heap_used_percent":54,
               "heap_committed_in_bytes":2130051072,
               "heap_max_in_bytes":2130051072,
               "non_heap_used_in_bytes":146981608,
               "non_heap_committed_in_bytes":154607616,
               "pools":{
                  "young":{
                     "used_in_bytes":135568192,
                     "max_in_bytes":139591680,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes":139591680,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes":139591680
                  },
                  "survivor":{
                     "used_in_bytes":4866896,
                     "max_in_bytes":17432576,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes":17432576,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes":17432576
                  },
                  "old":{
                     "used_in_bytes":1014597328,
                     "max_in_bytes":1973026816,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes":1638372912,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes":1973026816
                  }
               }
            },
            "threads":{
               "count":43,
               "peak_count":50
            },
            "gc":{
               "collectors":{
                  "young":{
                     "collection_count":170449,
                     "collection_time_in_millis":1934820
                  },
                  "old":{
                     "collection_count":847,
                     "collection_time_in_millis":38599
                  }
               }
            },
            "buffer_pools":{
               "direct":{
                  "count":32,
                  "used_in_bytes":67767443,
                  "total_capacity_in_bytes":67767442
               },
               "mapped":{
                  "count":108,
                  "used_in_bytes":68478134,
                  "total_capacity_in_bytes":68478134
               }
            },
            "classes":{
               "current_loaded_count":12473,
               "total_loaded_count":12527,
               "total_unloaded_count":54
            }
         },
         "thread_pool":{
            "bulk":{
               "threads":2,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":2,
               "completed":383422
            },
            "fetch_shard_started":{
               "threads":1,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":4,
               "completed":97
            },
            "fetch_shard_store":{
               "threads":0,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":0,
               "completed":0
            },
            "flush":{
               "threads":1,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":1,
               "completed":12854
            },
            "force_merge":{
               "threads":1,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":1,
               "completed":1240
            },
            "generic":{
               "threads":4,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":8,
               "completed":273461
            },
            "get":{
               "threads":2,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":2,
               "completed":4897
            },
            "index":{
               "threads":2,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":2,
               "completed":16
            },
            "listener":{
               "threads":1,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":1,
               "completed":21
            },
            "management":{
               "threads":3,
               "queue":0,
               "active":1,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":3,
               "completed":366004
            },
            "refresh":{
               "threads":1,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":1,
               "completed":21459450
            },
            "search":{
               "threads":4,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":4,
               "completed":463814
            },
            "snapshot":{
               "threads":0,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":0,
               "completed":0
            },
            "warmer":{
               "threads":0,
               "queue":0,
               "active":0,
               "rejected":0,
               "largest":0,
               "completed":0
            }
         },
         "fs":{
            "timestamp":1573740483888,
            "total":{
               "total_in_bytes":8577331200,
               "free_in_bytes":20480,
               "available_in_bytes":20480
            },
            "data":[
               {
                  "path":"/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0",
                  "mount":"/ (/dev/xvda1)",
                  "type":"xfs",
                  "total_in_bytes":8577331200,
                  "free_in_bytes":20480,
                  "available_in_bytes":20480,
                  "spins":"false"
               }
            ],
            "io_stats":{
               "devices":[
                  {
                     "device_name":"xvda1",
                     "operations":5857367,
                     "read_operations":171280,
                     "write_operations":5686087,
                     "read_kilobytes":13911088,
                     "write_kilobytes":304080912
                  }
               ],
               "total":{
                  "operations":5857367,
                  "read_operations":171280,
                  "write_operations":5686087,
                  "read_kilobytes":13911088,
                  "write_kilobytes":304080912
               }
            }
         },
         "transport":{
            "server_open":0,
            "rx_count":20,
            "rx_size_in_bytes":7538,
            "tx_count":20,
            "tx_size_in_bytes":7538
         },
         "http":{
            "current_open":20,
            "total_opened":2915
         },
         "breakers":{
            "request":{
               "limit_size_in_bytes":1278030643,
               "limit_size":"1.1gb",
               "estimated_size_in_bytes":0,
               "estimated_size":"0b",
               "overhead":1,
               "tripped":0
            },
            "fielddata":{
               "limit_size_in_bytes":1278030643,
               "limit_size":"1.1gb",
               "estimated_size_in_bytes":0,
               "estimated_size":"0b",
               "overhead":1.03,
               "tripped":0
            },
            "in_flight_requests":{
               "limit_size_in_bytes":2130051072,
               "limit_size":"1.9gb",
               "estimated_size_in_bytes":4396991,
               "estimated_size":"4.1mb",
               "overhead":1,
               "tripped":0
            },
            "parent":{
               "limit_size_in_bytes":1491035750,
               "limit_size":"1.3gb",
               "estimated_size_in_bytes":4396991,
               "estimated_size":"4.1mb",
               "overhead":1,
               "tripped":0
            }
         },
         "script":{
            "compilations":1,
            "cache_evictions":0
         },
         "discovery":{
            "cluster_state_queue":{
               "total":0,
               "pending":0,
               "committed":0
            }
         },
         "ingest":{
            "total":{
               "count":0,
               "time_in_millis":0,
               "current":0,
               "failed":0
            },
            "pipelines":{

            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is my Hibernate Search configurations with Spring boot 2.0 application.

```
spring:

  datasource:
    
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 30
      minimum-idle: 10
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        ejb:
          interceptor: com.xyz.xyz.xyz.util.EntityInterceptor
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 100
          order_inserts: true
          order_update: true
        search:
          autoregister_listeners: true
          fulltext_query: ERROR
          default_null_token: N/A
          error_handler: com.xyz.xyz.xyz.search.exceptions.HibernateSearchErrorHandler
          default:
            indexmanager: elasticsearch
            worker:
              execution: async
            elasticsearch:
              required_index_status: yellow
              index_schema_management_strategy: none
              host: ${ES_HOST:http://127.0.0.1:9200}
              request: ERROR
              log:
                json_pretty_printing: false
```

I am not understanding what is missing. Please guide me in right direction. Ask me if any other information require to understand my problem. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would need the code that performs the entity changes in order to be sure, but from what I understand:

- you are performing massive changes in your database
- Hibernate Search queues the corresponding index changes (thousands of them)
- Hibernate Search processes the queue asynchronously, but in large batches, sending very large indexing requests to Elasticsearch.
- Elasticsearch can't keep up and requests end up timing out

There are three solutions:

1. sending fewer requests to Elasticsearch at a time (smaller batches), so that Elasticsearch gets the same amount of time to index fewer documents.
2. allowing more time for Elasticsearch to handle each request.
3. increasing the indexing speed of Elasticsearch.

Number 1 would only be useful if your problem is caused by rare, short "bursts" of changes, which doesn't seem to be your case.
It is not possible in Hibernate Serach 5 anyway, but for the sake of completeness, here's how to do it in Hibernate Search 6 by configuring [indexing queues](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-elasticsearch-indexing-queues), with Spring Boot:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        search:
          backend:
            indexing.max_bulk_size: 50 # default is 100
```

Number 2 is probably not a good idea, since the default timeout is already quite large: 30 seconds (used to be 60 seconds in Hibernate Search 5). If you're getting timeouts, either Elasticsearch is very, very slow, or there are network problems that led to connection timeouts. In both cases it's concerning and you should have a look at your setup (see below).
If you really want to increase this timeout, use the property [`hibernate.search.backend.read_timeout`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#backend-elasticsearch-configuration-connection-tuning), in milliseconds (in Hibernate Search 5, it's `hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.read_timeout`).

Number 3 is the way to go, I think. You really should have a look at the configuration of your Elasticsearch cluster. Try to test and monitor your cluster to see if there are bottlenecks.

One easy-to-solve bottleneck is the number of simultaneous connections from Hibernate Search to Elasticsearch. By default in Hibernate Search 5.10 it's maximum 2 per Elasticsearch node and 20 per cluster. If you're only using one Elasticsearch node, that could be *very* limiting. Try raising it; here's how to do it in Hibernate Search 5:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        search:
          default:
            elasticsearch:
              max_total_connection_per_route: 10
```

With Hibernate Search 6 the default is already 10, but you can raise it regardless, if you think that makes sense:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        search:
          backend:
            max_connections_per_route: 20
```

Comment: Hi yrodiere, First Thanks for your response. Your understanding is absolutely correct that I am doing massive changes in database. I have updated my question and added the scenario and code. My Elastic Search is on EC2 instance of AWS in a VPN so network is not the issue. I have observed there are many simultaneous thread are working with large AddLuceneWork Queues . I will check my ES configurations and try to test with your provided properties. I will update you if this was not resolved.

Comment: Hi yrodiere, when Hibernate search 6.0.0 is gonna released for production use.

Comment: @Mubasher "When it's ready". There is no set date yet. That being said, the code is clean and well-tested; when it comes to Elasticsearch, it already works better than Search 5. Search 6 is only considered Beta because we will introduce backward-incompatible changes that will require you to update your code or reindex your data. If you're fine with that, you can already use it in production.

Comment: @Mubasher Judging from your code, one big problem is that you're executing everything in a single session and a single transaction. You should consider splitting the import into multiple transactions if possible, or at least flushing/clearing the session periodically. Do not forget to use [flushToIndexes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-batchindex-flushtoindexes) before each `session.clear()` to send indexing requests to Elasticsearch.

Comment: I am also using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate ORM and Hibernate Search.

Comment: If you want the whole import of 15,000+ complex entities to be transactional, then I'm not sure how to improve performance. Did setting the max total connection per route improve anything?